# Unable to use more than one Attributes when all Classes are not on the same page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, attributes

Am trying to write `onclick` attribute to different classes using JavaScript

```
    window.onload=function (){
    document.getElementsByClassName("sg")[0].setAttribute("onClick", "ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Submit a form', eventAction: 'Click', eventLabel: 'Contact form submit'});");    

    document.getElementsByClassName("sm")[0].setAttribute("onClick", "ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Submit a form', eventAction: 'Click', eventLabel: 'Contact form submit'});");  
    }
```

The problem is adding an attribute is working only if the all classes were on one page like the code above.But if i want to have the same code on another page which have different classes then non of the code will work for the both pages. and i will have this error in the Console:
`Cannot read property`'setAttribute'`of undefined at window.onload`

Here is my code:

```
    window.onload=function (){
    document.getElementsByClassName("sg")[0].setAttribute("onClick", "ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Submit a form', eventAction: 'Click', eventLabel: 'Contact form submit'});"); 

    document.getElementsByClassName("sm")[0].setAttribute("onClick", "ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Submit a form', eventAction: 'Click', eventLabel: 'Contact form submit'});");   

    document.getElementsByClassName("sf")[0].setAttribute("onClick", "ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Submit a form', eventAction: 'Click', eventLabel: 'Contact form submit'});");   
    }
```

Comment: You should use `addEventListener` instead of manipulating the `onClick` attribute.

Comment: Also, you should probably use a loop. That way, it will work whether there's 0, 1 or many elements matching that class.

Answer (score 0):

Test if the element exists before you try to call a method on it.

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("foo")[0];
if (element) {
    element.setAttribute(etc, etc);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.But that didnot work for me.
window.onload = function() {

var element_b = document.getElementsByClassName("sh")[0];
if (element_b) {
    element.setAttribute("onClick", "ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Submit1', eventAction: 'Click', eventLabel: 'Contact1'});");    
}
var element_c = document.getElementsByClassName("fl-node-5935630735960")[0];
if (element_c) {
    element.setAttribute("onClick", "ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Submit2', eventAction: 'Click', eventLabel: 'Contact2'});");    
}
   
};

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
function myEventHandler
{
    ga('send', 'event',
    {
        eventCategory: 'Submit a form',
        eventAction: 'Click',
        eventLabel: 'Contact form submit'
    });
}

['sg','sm','sf'].forEach(function(k)
{
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(k)).forEach(function(o)
    {
        o.addEventListener('click',myEventHandler);
    }
});
```

This will work whether there are 0, 1 or many elements matching each class.

Comment: Thank you
The code will work if the event will be the same for all classes.I did edit the code to let it become different event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use addEventListener to catch the event

```
window.addEventListener('click', function($event){
  var eleClasses = $event.target.classList;
  if(eleC.contains("sg") || eleC.contains("sm") || eleC.contains("sf")){
    ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Submit a form', eventAction: 'Click', eventLabel: 'Contact form submit'})
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you The code will work if the event will be the same for all classes.I did edit the code to let it become different event. –